# PKCS11 token, receiving error CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID when executing keystore.getKey()

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I use java 1.8 and the following code works for many USB pkcs11 devices but this week I found a new model of a token that when I execute "keystorePkcs11.getKey(alias, pass);" I receive the error CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID. This token has a single certificate

This is the full code source I used to do the test:

```
package pkcs11test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_TOKEN_INFO;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11;
import sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception;

public class PKCS11Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            char[] pass = "******".toCharArray(); // PIN of the token
            String dllFile = "D:\\temp\\cryptoide_pkcs11.dll"; // DLL file used to acces the token
            String configFile = "config.cfg"; // config file
            PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance(dllFile, "C_GetFunctionList", null, false);
            long[] slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);
            for (int j = 0; j < slots.length; j++) {
                CK_TOKEN_INFO tokenInfo = p11.C_GetTokenInfo(slots[j]);
                System.err.println("Token found at position "+j+
                    " label "+new String(tokenInfo.label).toUpperCase().trim()+
                    " model "+new String(tokenInfo.model).toUpperCase().trim()+
                    " manufacturerID "+new String(tokenInfo.manufacturerID).toUpperCase().trim()+
                    " utcTime "+new String(tokenInfo.utcTime).toUpperCase().trim()+
                    " serial "+new String(tokenInfo.serialNumber).toUpperCase().trim());

                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(configFile));
                out.print("name=SmartCard\r\n"+"library="+dllFile+"\r\nslotListIndex="+slots[j]+"\r\n");
                out.close();

                SunPKCS11 tempProv = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configFile);
                KeyStore keystorePkcs11 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs11", tempProv);
                keystorePkcs11.load(null, pass);
                KeyManagerFactory kKeyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("sunx509");
                //kKeyManagerFactory.init(keystorePkcs11, null);

                Enumeration<String> enume = keystorePkcs11.aliases(); // read aliases from token
                while(enume.hasMoreElements()) { // token has a single certificate
                    String alias = (String) enume.nextElement();
                    System.err.println(alias);
                    Certificate cert = keystorePkcs11.getCertificate(alias);
                    System.err.println("Cert to string "+cert.toString());
                    **keystorePkcs11.getKey(alias, pass);** // Error is HERE
                    PrivateKey priv = (PrivateKey)(keystorePkcs11.getKey(alias, pass));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | PKCS11Exception | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PKCS11Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And the full output and error is:

```
Token found at position 0 label MTOKEN CRYPTOID model E manufacturerID LONGMAI utcTime  serial AE09D489************
A certificate object
Cert to string [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=**************, SURNAME=************, GIVENNAME=************, SERIALNUMBER=*************, EMAILADDRESS=**************, OU=OG, O=*****************, L=****, ST=******, C=RO, T=*****
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  ...............................
]
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineGetKey(P11KeyStore.java:330)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at pkcs11test.PKCS11Test.main(PKCS11Test.java:55)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetAttributeValue(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_GetAttributeValue(PKCS11.java:1623)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.loadPkey(P11KeyStore.java:1298)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineGetKey(P11KeyStore.java:315)
    ... 2 more
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the Token also come with a Logging DLL ? Could you activate it and also post the PKCS#11 Logs from the Library if possible.

Comment: I can't find any docs about this, but the DLL with the name cryptoide_pkcs11.dll is the only one that cames with this token and has function C_GetFunctionList implemented. I will also ask at the Longmai online contact.

Comment: As we can clearly see here, it is attempting a "PKCS11.C_GetAttributeValue" where it gets the CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID. So chances are that the object being returned does not contain a prperty that Java is expecting. I've had issues with CKR_ID at times. I'd suggest that you try it with Native C and look at all the attributes present in the Object and compare it with other PKCS#11 tokens you have. The difference should tell you where the problem lies.

Comment: I tried OpenSC but I don't think I can get the object atributtes using it. OpenSC  signs succesfuly data using this token. When you suggested to try Native C you mean to make my own implementation or to use another existing implementation? This token is working well in other programming languages. Apps made in Microsoft Net Framework don't have this problem. Also web apps that use this token work well(on IE an Chrome).  I seems that Java has a problem(is asking for a property that is missing). Can't I just ignore this error somehow and move on?

Comment: I'm curious about what is this "missing property". But even if I will identify it, would this help my cause? I don't think so, I can't change this property as it is implemented in the token driver. Is this correct?

Comment: The attribute that causes the problem is CKA_MODULUS.

Comment: If it is an extra attribute which is optional for an object in other drivers, but must for this, you could consider getting rid of it on the token (modify object ) or if it is a missing attribute, you could add it if it doesn't hurt other apis . I would definitely give it a shot

Comment: How can I change an attribute like CKA_MODULUS on the token? I looked at OpenSC, pkcs11-toos but it seems that this tool can only change CKA_ID.